# How to recursively remove execute permissions from files without touching folders?

Tags: permissions, executable, recursive

I made a backup to an NTFS drive, and well, this backup really proved necessary. However, the NTFS drive messed up permissions. I'd like to restore them to normal w/o manually fixing each and every file.

One problem is that suddenly all my text files gained execute permissions, which is wrong ofc. So I tried:

```
sudo chmod -R a-x folder\ with\ restored\ backup/
```

But it is wrong as it removes the `x` permission from directories as well which makes them unreadable.

What is the correct command in this case?

Comment: Meta: I've never understood why Unix systems add the execute bit to files mounted from DOS or Windows file systems. It's not like anybody's ever going to execute those files. I generally add "noexec" to my mount options wherever practical.

Answer (score 117, accepted):

If you are fine with setting the execute permissions for everyone on all folders:

```
chmod -R -x+X -- 'folder with restored backup'
```

The `-x` removes execute permissions for all
The `+X` will add execute permissions for all, but *only* for directories.

See [Stéphane Chazelas's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297040/80216) for a solution
that uses `find` to really not touch folders, as requested.

Comment: The command I eventually used to restore permissions to normal: `chmod -R a-x+X,u-x+rwX,go-wx+rX directory/ name\`

Comment: Also see [Edward's answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297014/111262) about exception for BSD

Comment: This fails the "without touching folders" requirement.  What if execute (maybe for world) has been intentionally removed on some directories?  You should not be adding it.

Comment: this did not work on Mac. Moving the -R flag to the beginning will make this work in both linux and Mac terminals. `chmod -R -x+x *`

Comment: @JoeMoe1984 I'm not surprised - options are supposed to be specified before arguments, and in this case `-x+X` is an argument.  I'm actually surprised it works as illustrated.

Comment: Thank you @gaazkam! That specific variation was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: Actually with the correct order it runs on OSX, but it doesn't actually have the desired effect. You have to do it as two separate steps: `chmod -R -x * && chmod -R +X *`

Comment: And you have to run as `sudo` otherwise the `+X` doesn't have permission to recurse into subdirectories.

Comment: Use the comma, and no don't use `sudo`. It is dangerous, and I don't know why you need it.

Answer (score 20):

Ok, I re-read the "chmod" man pages for Mac OS X, BSD, and Linux, and did a few experiments. Here is what I learned about symbolic modes. It can get complicated, but it's worth understanding:

- The general form is *clause*[,*clause*…] where:
- *clause* := [ugoa][+-=][rwxXstugo]
- [ugoa] (**who**) (specify multiple) means set the permission for user, group, other, or all. If not specified, the default is 'a', but the [umask](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Umask) is in effect.
- [+-=] (**action**) (specify one) means:

  - + means add the specified permissions to the permissions already in effect
  - - means remove the specified permissions from the permissions already in effect
  - = means set the permissions to the specified permissions, clearing all others
- [rwxXstugo] (**permission**) (specify multiple of rwxXst OR one of ugo) sets the permissions for the specified user(s) as follows:

  - r — read
  - w — write
  - x — execute/search
  - X — execute/search iff directory OR any execute bit was already set.
  - s — suid or sgid
  - t — [sticky](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sticky_bit)
  - u — copy user permission
  - g — copy group permission
  - o — copy other permission

So for example, `a+x` would make a file executable by everybody. `a+X` would make a file executable by everybody IF it had been executable by anybody.

`a+x` would make a directory searchable by everybody. `a+X` would also make a directory searchable by everybody.

The key difference between BSD and Linux is that with BSD, the determination is made based on the file's permissions *before* chmod was executed. While with Linux, the determination is made immediately before the +X clause is executed.

So with BSD, the combination `a-x,a+X` would remove execute/search permission and then make a directory searchable by everybody, and make a file executable by everybody *if* it had originally been executable by anybody.

With Linux, `a-x,a+X` would remove execute/search permission and then make a directory searchable by everybody, while leaving a file executable by nobody.

---

Here's a concrete example: on a BSD machine: a directory, an executable file, and a non-executable file:

```
drwxr-x---  2 falk  staff  68 Jul 19 18:01 fee/
-rwxr-x---  1 falk  staff   0 Jul 19 18:01 fie*
-rw-r-----  1 falk  staff   0 Jul 19 18:01 foe
```

Observe that both the directory and "fie" are executable/searchable by the user, but not by others.

Now we execute `chmod a-x,a+X *`. The first clause will strip the execute/search bit from all users for all files, but the second clause will add it back for both "fee" and "fie". "fee" because it's a directory, and "fie" because it had at least one executable bit to start with.

```
drwxr-x--x  2 falk  staff  68 Jul 19 18:01 fee/
-rwxr-x--x  1 falk  staff   0 Jul 19 18:01 fie*
-rw-r-----  1 falk  staff   0 Jul 19 18:01 foe
```

I had the same result executing `chmod -x+X`.

Conclusion: Jak Gibb's solution will work on Linux, but for BSD, you would need to make two passes.

I didn't test this on SVr4 or other Unix variants.

Comment: Nice read. Thanks for doing the research into this.

Comment: Nice comparison, but I wonder if he difference is between Linux and BSD or between Gnu `chmod` and BSD `chmod`: Is the difference in the kernel or the process.

Answer (score 14):

One way to do it:

```
find backup -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} +
```

Comment: This could wind up adding or removing permissions you didn't want to change. Better to use `chmod a-x {}`

Comment: @EdwardFalk `chmod a-x {}` could also end up removing permissions you didn't want to change, and it could leave files world-writeable.  The point is, 0644 is a "generally reasonable" compromise.  The OP should, of course, also engage brain before applying solutions from the Internet on his computer.

Comment: "a-x" removes execute permission for user, group, other, and leaves the other permissions unchanged, as far as I know. Do I have that wrong?

Comment: @EdwardFalk No, you're right.  But you don't know what the set of files really is, and you also don't know what the permissions before `chmod` are.  If the backup files contain scripts and binaries, removing `x` from them is wrong.  If the permissions before `chmod` are 0777 then `chmod a-x` will still leave them 0666, which is probably not what you want.  What I'm saying is that `chmod 0644` is better heuristics, not that `chmod a-x` is wrong.

Comment: @EdwardFalk: Not quite.  *Any* use of `chmod` will clobber the setgid bit if you're not a member of the file's group, for obvious security reasons.

Comment: The question specifically asks for how to remove exec permissions on all files, nothing else. `chmod a-x` does that, `chmod 0644` does something else. If you were worried about others modifying your files then they wouldn't have been 777 to being with.

Comment: @NajibIdrissi Except when, you know, they changed to 0777 when you copied them on a foreign filesystem that doesn't have UNIX permissions.  Which is exactly what the OP did.

Answer (score 14):

```
 find backup ! -type l ! -type d -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

Would remove execute permission to files that are not of type *directory* (as you requested) nor *symbolic link* (symlinks are generally always rwxrwxrwx, and `chmod` would affect the target of the symlink on them).

Note that:

```
 find backup -type f -exec chmod a-x {} +
```

would only change the permission of *regular* files. That would exclude *directories* and *symlinks*, but also *devices*, *named pipes*, *sockets* and possibly others depending on the system (though in the OP's case of a backup of a NTFS file system, those would be unlikely to be present).

Answer (score 4):

In zsh, use the [glob qualifier](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Glob-Qualifiers) `.` to match only regular files (not including symbolic links), and `D` to match dot files:

```
sudo chmod a-x folder\ with\ restored\ backup/**/*(D.)
```

If the command line is too long, you can use [`zargs`](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/User-Contributions.html#index-zargs):

```
zargs -- folder\ with\ restored\ backup/**/*(D.) -- sudo chmod a-x
```