# Space after filename (Linux)

Tags: linux, filenames, executable

Whats different  "name.txt" vs "name.txt " in Linux?

If I rename `name.bin` to  `name.txt` - is normal and file doesn't executable.

If I rename `name.bin` to `file.txt` (with space after filename) - file will be executable.

Comment: Please prove that assertion, as it is a bit difficult to believe.

Comment: what did you use to "rename" `name.bin` to `file.txt\ `? if you use `cp name.bin file.txt\ ` and `file.txt\ ` already exists and is executable, it will stay that way; `cp` without the `-p` flag won't change its permissions.

Comment: Perhaps you're failing to invoke the correct filename? Demonstrate what you're doing so we can follow along.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor https://attack.mitre.org/wiki/Technique/T1151

Comment: @interesting, but not a Linux thing, it is a file manager thing. So you are changing weather the file-manager attempts to execute it (not weather it is executable). A simpler solution is to prevent downloaders from setting the execute bit.

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor thanks a lot! just I bad speak English!

Comment: @Ctrl-alt-delor it might be a GUI file manager thing though. I might try this out.

Comment: @roaima, yes that is what I said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether the file is executable (or not) is a matter of permissions, not of the name.

Use `chmod a+x` to make it executable and `chmod a-x` to disallow it. Full details here:

https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/297014/255708